# Magic Lantern or native specs in 2020

Tags: canon, chromakey, bitrate, magic-lantern

I am photographer and videographer and my main subject is product photography (antiques,  watches, jewelry,...) and one of my biggest issue is poor sharpness and bad looking video from my Canon 77D. I do so many macro shots as well as chroma but the results are very poor, if sometimes not usable, and they require so many hour of noise cleaning that compromises the sharpness a lot.

I was planning to upgrade to the Fujifilm XT4 wich offers native 10-bit 4k at an impressive bitrate of 400mbs. That would solve my issues, however I am considering the  fact that I own may Canon's glass (like the 2nd version of the 24-70 2.8L), since I want to upgrade for getting  better video results, I am not sure if it worth considering the 5D mkIII with Magic Lantern, wich seems to allow 4k ROW at 14-bits. It is way cheaper for me and easier to get in short term.

I am truly confused guys with the "exact specs" ML allows in the 5D III, and if it worth considering it in 2020. So I highly appreciate your recommendations.

About the 5D mkIII specs I would appreciate if someone can tell me of there is a crop as you get in high resolution, if the footage is sharp, what is the maximum bitrate, what is the maximum frame rate, and what are the limitation of pushing the specs toward the limits.... what is the most best/usable/stable you can get form ML in the 5D mkIII?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll see an improvement with the 5Diii over the 77D without installing Magic Lantern, because the former has a full frame sensor, and the latter only an aps-c sensor.  Then, you're free to experiment with ML, use it if you like it, return to the normal firmware if you don't.  The major limitation that ML overcomes (in my opinion) is the maximum video duration.  Yes, it adds other bells and whistles, but it won't alter the fundamental physics of the camera, which is what you're getting by upgrading to a larger sensor.

Comment: And do considering the XT-4, do you think is worth it?

Comment: I haven't used one, so I don't really know.  I looked up the sensor size, though, and it's also aps-c, so it's probably on par with the 77D.  Sensor size is a big deal, will get you better low light performance (good for macro), and better depth of field, simply because it can sample more photons.  Any software or processing tricks that make smaller sensors perform well can always be applied to larger sensors, too, which means they'll always have an edge when it comes to image quality.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. Quiet appreciated